# iif in SSRS with multiple values

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have a field in the report which depends on 3 more fields in the DataSet. The 3 fields are APAC, EMEA and LATAM (Regions). Now There is a Yes and a No in those fields for corresponding Projects. I have to collect the fields with a Yes from each project and display all those regions as Impacted regions in a single field.. Is there a way to do it in SSRS. When I'm using iif I'm only able to display only one region.. supposed if 2 fields have yes, I'm not able to display both..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about concatenating the results?

```
=iif( Fields!APAC.value = "yes", "APAC ", "") & iif( Fields!EMEA.value = "yes", "EMEA ", "") & iif( Fields!LATAM.value = "yes", "LATAM", "")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response it doesn't work.. Says Error BC30518.. Overload resolution failed because no accesible "=" can be called with these arguments..

Comment: That error would be because of the datatype of the fields. I don't know what the datatpe is but if it is a boolen then you can drop the = "yes" altogether. If it is an int then you want to change the = "yes" to <> 0.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use SQL to solve your issue - change the query to return an extra field which is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a switch statement?

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/20/60693.aspx

Or... can you say what data type your parameters are and if they are multi-select or single select parameters?